# How to count total number of student based on multiple and conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get count of students based on multiple "and" condition
eg: Count number of students where student not in 10th class and student_in ["A", "B"] Grade and students subject is maths.

I have already tried with aggregation query but don't know how to make and condition it it

```
'{"aggs": {"num_of_students": {"terms": {"field": "student"}}}}'
```

Please help.

Expected Result: count number of students based on "and" condition.
Actual Result: Getting number of all students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use bool query along with aggs to apply aggregation only on the query result like below**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "class": 10
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "grade": "A B"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "num_of_students": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "student"
      }
    }
  }
}
```